# Spring @ModelAttribute interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-web

How can I have an interface as a `ModelAttribute` as in the below scenario?

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public String get(@PathVariable String id, ModelMap map) {
  map.put("entity", service.getById(id));
  return "view";
}

@PostMapping("/{id}")
public String update(@ModelAttribute("entity") Entity entity) {
  service.store(entity);
  return "view";
}
```

Above snippet gives the follow errors

```
BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [foo.Entity]: Specified class is an interface
```

I don't want spring to instantiate `entity` for me, I want to use the **existing** instance provided by `map.put("entity", ..)`.

Comment: Have you feelup `entity` object on view side ?

Comment: Thymeleaf form: `<form th:object="${entity}">..</form>`

Comment: ok that is correct , and make sure your property names in that entity class is the same name with `th:field`

Comment: @JohanSjöberg Is the entity stored in the session? Otherwise it wouldn't survive a request/response cycle.

Comment: @Kayaman no it's not. Good to know.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg It's *essential* to know. The view uses the model to fill out any dynamic parts, but the actual object isn't being kept around. It all gets transformed to whatever the view technology is (such as HTML) and the response data is discarded. Conversely when a request comes in, a new object is created, filled with the data coming in from the client and presented to you in a nice Java object form. You'll have to come up with an alternative solution. I'd suggest separate methods, otherwise you'll end up with complicated and less readable code. Forget about storing it in the session too.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg Have you confirm that your fields name and your entity class's property names are same ?

Comment: @ParthSolanki I have. I believe Kayaman is correct, the instance of the object does not survive the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As been pointed out in comments, the `Entity` instance does not survive between the `get` and `post` requests.

The solution is this

```
@ModelAttribute("entity")
public Entity entity(@PathVariable String id) {
    return service.getById(id);
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public String get() {
   return "view";
}

@PostMapping("/{id})
public String update(@ModelAttribute("entity") Entity entity) {
  service.store(entity);
  return "view";
}
```

What happens here is that the `Entity` in `update` binds to the `Entity` created from the `@ModelAttribute` annotated `entity` method. Spring then applies the form-values to the existing object.